# PulseAudio GUI images

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, devices

Can anyone tell me what the symbols mean in the sound manager GUI under the "Output Devices" tab?

There is one symbol that is a green rectangle and a blue music note.
The other is a dark grey square with a red "not allowed" symbol.

[image]

I ask because I have been having some trouble with the G930 device. I am wondering if this is a warning of some type.

P.S. sorry for the simple question. I found alot of command line documentation but not much on the GUI for PulseAudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green rectangle indicates 'hardware' and the music note indicates 'audio', so together they indicate your sound card. For your headset, the black square wit the no entry sign means there is no image available to display, meaning Linux doesn't have a graphic to represent that headset. They are just symbols to make things look nice